# Does a vector graphics format capable of the following exist?

Tags: vector

Take the following image, for example:

[image: Donald Duck]

I'd like to represent the lineart *not* as a black-filled, closed object, but as a network of Bézier curves connected at odd places, with various and varying stroke widths between them.  When I manipulate a curve that has other curves connected to it on its arc (not just at its endpoints), the other curves should adjust to stay connected to the one I'm manipulating.

Additionally, I'd like to represent the coloring as a set of "fill points" that, when rendering the image, propagate their color out in a wavefront until they encounter a Bézier curve - just like a flood fill tool in raster programs, just not prerendered.

Is there a vector graphics format (and editor) with which this can be done?  I've only had casual access to Inkscape/SVG, but the graphics primitives it offers are indeed too primitive.

Comment: Is the included picture here free?

Comment: @Kurt: Iunno? Random picture I found by Google Search. Source page is http://scratchpad.wikia.com/wiki/Donald_Duck_(Character).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe what you are after, for the most part, exists. That's simply not how vector graphics, or Bezier curves, work within existing tools in my experience.

While you can certainly introduce some line vocabulary into a Bezier curve, Bezier curves generally have a start and stop point and don't connect "at odd places".

The "fill points" idea is an interesting one. There are tools which will fill similar to flood fill tools in raster applications - Adobe Illustrator **Live Paint Bucket Tool** is one such tool. But fills aren't represented as a collection of "points until they collide with a curve". Objects have edges and those edges are treated as the boundary for the fill.

Comment: While curves don't connect, the start point of one curve might be manipulated if it lies on another curve which is altered. We're getting into animation territory (which fits nicely with Donald Duck).